# SQL Update Left Join - however if no records put 0 in field

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

This query works, however I need it to do something additional that I can't figure out how to do. I need the query to put a 0 into the "activityTempBookings" field if there are no records returned in the LEFT JOIN section. This is so that it overwrites older data where there are no activities with a future "tempReserveDate" even though in the past the may have been.

```
    UPDATE P
    SET activityTempBookings = t.bookingTempTotal
    FROM [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities] AS P 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT tempActivityID, SUM(tempPlaces) bookingTempTotal 
            FROM [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings] 
            WHERE tempReserveDate > GETDATE () 
            GROUP BY tempActivityID
    )t
    ON t.tempActivityID = p.activityID
```

Any help greatly appreciated - Please don't think I'm rude but I may not respond until Monday.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `COALESCE` which basically *returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.*

```
UPDATE P
SET    activityTempBookings = COALESCE(t.bookingTempTotal, 0)
FROM   [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities] AS P 
       LEFT JOIN 
       (
           SELECT tempActivityID, 
                  SUM(tempPlaces) bookingTempTotal 
           FROM   [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings] 
           WHERE  tempReserveDate > GETDATE () 
           GROUP  BY tempActivityID
       ) t ON t.tempActivityID = p.activityID
```

- [TSQL COALESCE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNULL

```
UPDATE P
    SET activityTempBookings = ISNULL(t.bookingTempTotal,0)
    FROM [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities] AS P 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT tempActivityID, SUM(tempPlaces) bookingTempTotal 
            FROM [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings] 
            WHERE tempReserveDate > GETDATE () 
            GROUP BY tempActivityID
    )t
    ON t.tempActivityID = p.activityID
```